# Property 'id' is optional in type A but required in type B after if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, frontend

TS 4.1.3. The Error is called as  `Argument of type 'Task' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ id: string; }'.   Property 'id' is optional in type 'Task' but required in type '{ id: string; }'.` The error occured in functions below

```
interface Task {
    id?: string
    message: string,
}

const handleClickTask = (task: Task) => {
    if (task.id) {
        getTask(task)
    }
}

const getTask = (taskWithId: { id: string }) => {

}
```

[image]

Link to the TS playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwM4GtkG8CwAUMicsACYD8AXMhmFKAOZGnIC2EGGcTEt9RiCYAaIgF8iRBAHsQ9ZAAs4IcgBsIAYTXAEWdNmQBeZAAowmLLQNYAlMYB8eVqWAwzF7ADoK9gsTZSPjAbc0tbFxJJQmjpOQVgm2MPSwB1YDBFAElyWlwyXLoGZmRxeyMnfwkgA

How to fix it and why the error is occured?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way here is to use union types

First approach:

```js
/**
 * First approach
 */
type Task_0 = {
    id: string
    message: string,
}

type Task_1 = {
    id: undefined,
    message: string,
}

type Task = Task_0 | Task_1

const handleClickTask = (task: Task) => {
    if (task.id) {
        getTask(task)
    }
}

const getTask = (taskWithId: { id: string }) => {

}
```

Second approach:

```js
/**
 * Second approach
 */
type Task_0 = {
    id: string
    message: string,
}

type Task_1 = {
    message: string,
}

type Task = Task_0 | Task_1

const isId = (task: any): task is Task_0 => typeof task.id === 'string'

const handleClickTask = (task: Task) => {
    if (isId(task)) {
        getTask(task)
    }
}

const getTask = (taskWithId: { id: string }) => {

}
```

More explanations:

```js
interface Task {
    id?: string
    message: string,
}

const handleClickTask = (task: Task) => {

    if (task.id) {
        /**
         * Here, TS still treats taks as a Task type, where your ID can be optional
         */
        getTask(task)
    }
}

const getTask = (taskWithId: { id: string }) => {

}

{
    interface Task {
        id?: string,
        message: string,
    }

    const handleClickTask = (task: Task) => {

        if (typeof task.id === 'string') {
            const id = task.id; // string
            const oldTask = task; // Task, where id still can be undefined

            const test1 = getTask(oldTask) // error, type is referenced to Task type


            getTask({
                ...task,
                id
            }) // ok
        }
    }

    /**
     * this function expects {id: string} which is not compatible with {id?: string}
     * So, you need to pass as an argument to this function type, which will be
     * compatible with {id: string}
     * 
     * THat's why I created union type, when one of property is {id: string}
     */
    const getTask = (taskWithId: { id: string }) => {

    }
}
```

[Here](https://catchts.com/unions) you can find more examples/approaches with unions

Comment: Ty you for that detailed answer. But I need to know, why TS don't figure out that id is exist in type Task after if statement.

Comment: @DmitriyGlazkov make sense. I added more expanations

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way in which you defined `id` in the interface `Task`. There, `id` is defined using `?`, which in typescript translates to: this is either a `string` or `undefined`.

When you pass a task to `getTask`, you take out the id from task, but now you said that `id` is required, i.e. it is of type `string`, whereas the interface says it is either `string`, either `undefined`.

For it to work, `getTask` should be defined with `?` after `id` (just like in the interface), like so:

```
const getTask = (taskWithId: { id?: string }) => {

}
```

Comment: You can refer to this part from the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters)

Comment: I think the dilemma here is when the OP has ensured that `task` indeed have a valid `id`, why is TS still complaining? Shouldn't it be able to figure it out by looking at the control flow?

Comment: I don't think it does that because `getTask` might be called with a task which could not have a valid id (with the arguments defined as the OP), which in typescript is not valid, as id could be undefined for a task.

Comment: I think it complies because of the fact that getTask can be called with a task that has no id, thus one cannot destructure `id` from that

Comment: I agree with Nishant. The main answer was why after check, that id is exist in type Task we have error.

Answer (score 0):

**fix**

```
interface Task {
        id?: string,
        message: string,
    }
    
    const handleClickTask = (task: Task) => {
        if (task.id) {
            getTask(task)
        }
    }
    
    const getTask = (taskWithId: { id?: string}) => {
    

    }
```

**Why the error happened?**
The error happened because the interface Task has made id property as optional.
But in taskWithId the id is mandatory and therefore it complains because the types didn't match.

In the interface Task the type of id is string or undefined.But in taskWithId it is only string.